# Typescript debug with line number

Tags: javascript, browser, typescript

Opening up the console in a browser shows the javascript line number of a function call or error message.

But I am using TypeScript which is being compiled to Javascript.

Is there a way I can get the line numbers for TypeScript?

I am using VSCode as my editor

Comment: make sure you are generating '.map' files when you compile.

Comment: yes the '.map' file is being generated..what to do next

Answer (score -1):

There are source maps, but the simple thing to do is to navigate to the source, provided that for development it's not being uglified and rollified and minified, in that case you need source maps.

Otherwise simply using the generated JavaScript file usually points to what the issue might be in the source code. If this sounds cumbersome you can always open a side by side view of source and the built JS.